# "Confirmed" synonym with negative connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

Just as *infamous* is synonymous with *famous* but with an additional negative connotation, and *notorious* is a negative-connotation synonym of *renowned*, I'm looking for a negative-connotation synonym of ***confirmed***.

**Context**: An initial review has identified what is believed to be a defect. A closer review has *confirmed* the defect. I need a single word (a *very* short phrase might suffice) to describe the confirmed defects.

Comment: er... *defective* or *faulty*.

Comment: When you went through the list of synonyms from a thesaurus, which words seemed better to you than others?

Comment: @HotLicks [none of them](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/confirm); they're all too positive

Comment: So, what's wrong with "verified"?

Comment: @HotLicks there's no negative connotation

Comment: In court cases, lawyers often try to put a negative spin on testimony elicited from a hostile witness confirming some detail of fact in the case by characterizing the confirmation as an "admission." So in some contexts you could contrast "confirmed" with **admitted**. Another, similar (but slightly milder) term is **acknowledged**. In both instances the sense of the word is "confirmed under pressure or unwillingly."

Comment: When I read this question, I immediately thought of ***corroborated***.  From the thesaurus page you linked to, I would also pick out ***substantiated***, ***upheld*** (past participle of *uphold*) and ***borne out*** (past participle of *bear out*).  I guess none of them really has a negative connotation; ISTM that these might have less of a positive connotation than ***confirmed*** or ***verified***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Acknowledged*** defects might serve your purpose: with terms which themselves have a negative sense, *acknowledge* often has overtones of admitting something 'against interest'.

Comment: Not really negative, but probably as close as I'm going to get. Thx @StoneyB!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the term ***nailed*** (defects) serves your purpose.

Definition 3 below implies the *usual* negative connotation, whereas definition 7 below allows it to be used in your context.

M-W:

> **[nail](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nail)**
> *verb*
>
> **3 a** :  catch, trap
>
> **3 b** :  to expose usually so as to discredit
>
> **3 c** :  to arrest or punish for an offense
>
> **7** :  to settle, **establish**, or represent clearly and unmistakably —often used with down